# Feature to intersperse edit history with comment history

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indicate which revision of a question or answer a comment relates to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25997/indicate-which-revision-of-a-question-or-answer-a-comment-relates-to)

It's not uncommon for a commenter to rightfully remark about a question early on (maybe providing a constructive criticism), followed by the OP editing the question accordingly, followed by a slew of comments remarking on how the first commenter is out of place. This occurs when people don't pay attention to the timing of edits vs comments.

This can occur in answers too.

It would be useful to see a chronology of edits and comments visually interspersed for flow.

For example,

[Can I upload photos but not post to wall in Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873147/can-i-upload-photos-but-not-post-to-wall-in-facebook)

At the time I saw it:

[alt text http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/1993/examplei.jpg](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/1993/examplei.jpg)

The edits looked like this:
[alt text http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/1211/2example.jpg](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/1211/2example.jpg)

Comment: Got that feature request right here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25997/where-be-the-breadcrumbs

Comment: Thanks. I added an upvote to the original question.